# How to make objects in canvas unselectable?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to make all object in canvas unselectable. I've found [selectable](http://fabricjs.com/docs/symbols/fabric.Object.html#selectable) method but i didn't find the way to implement it to all objects.

Comment: You can use `fabric.StaticCanvas` which lacks selection of any kind. Or you can use `canvas.forEachObject(function(object){ object.selectable = false })` to make all objects on canvas unselectable.

Comment: @kangax, you probably want to put that in an answer so yevgen kan accept it

Answer (score 16):

I was looking for an **unmovable** and **uneditable** Fabric Text and I finally found a solution combining several SO, hope I can save someone some time.

Using *"selectable": false* wasn't enough in my case : the text was still editable and the cursor was still the "movable cursor" (even if the object wasn't selectable).

I had to add **"evented": false**. Here is an example:

```
this.canvas.add(new fabric.Text("Hello world !", {
            "selectable": false,
            "evented": false
}));
```

You can play with different control options here : http://fabricjs.com/controls-customization

Answer (score 11):

You can make all the elements un-selectable using below code

```
canvas.deactivateAll();
canvas.renderAll();
canvas.forEachObject(function(object){ 
       object.selectable = false; 
});
```

Comment: Possibly an API change, `canvas.deactivateAll();` doesn't seem to exist any more.

Comment: you can use `canvas.discardActiveObject()` instead since `canvas.deactivateAll()` is no longer exists

Answer (score 7):

There is a way like this in option -

```
selectable: false

      or 

object.set({selectable:false})

      or


 object.selectable = false;
```

Comment: object.set('selectable', false);

Answer (score 0):

On a parent HTML element use css property `pointer-events`:

```
.locked {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

To set this property from javascript:

```
let canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas-container")[0]
canvasElement.classList.add("locked")
```

To unlock canvas:

```
canvasElement.classList.remove("locked")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas._objects.forEach(obj => {obj.selectable = false;});
canvas.discardActiveObject();
```

This should do the trick! `discardActiveObject` should fire events that request a rerender, so you don't need to manually invoke `renderAll`. In general, you should always use `requestRenderAll` instead of `renderAll`.